# Why is MySQL running as a single process?

Tags: mariadb

I have two MariaDB(InnoDB) linux servers. Even if `my.cnf` is *almost* the same they behave very differently. On the *bad* machine MariaDB is ver 10.0.16-MariaDB-1, on the good machine is 10.0.27-MariaDB-0+deb8u1.

They act on different same-size databases (around 3GB) similar in structure and usage. The *bad* machine has a few more clients (7 against 4) reading the data. DBs don't perform any calculation: they just provide storage.

Checking the OS processes with top/htop I see that the one that misbehaves has **only ONE process**, while the *good* one has **31 distinct PIDs**. I could imagine that this is the bottleneck.

MySQLTuner returns a big difference for `table cache hit rate`: bad machine 6% (400/6K opened), good machine 118% (400/338 opened).

This is the configuration of the *bad* one. 
Where can I **set the max number of processes**? Or is there something else I didn't take in account?

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = XXXXXX
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
innodb_file_per_table  = 1
innodb_file_format     = barracuda

skip-name-resolve

bind-address        = XX.XX.XX.XX

#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 128M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10


#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log


expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name


#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem


[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M
```

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM?  Are the connections doing "reads"?  Or "writes"?

Comment: And, what query is running when you do `SHOW PROCESSLIST` on each machine?  What is the value of `table_open_cache`?  Is only one table involved?  If so, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: And...  The 1 vs 31 may or may not be a useful clue.  Legitimate other issues could lead to that difference.

Comment: @RickJames, thank you for answering:
`innodb_buffer_pool_size` is in both cases 0; 
RAM is 4GB; 
connections are both reading and writing: writing is mostly 1 line every 5 seconds + burst of heavy read every 5 minutes; `table_open_cache` is the default 400.

Comment: show create table (I created a new dummy table) is the same, charset apart (in the *bad* db it is utf-8):

`| temp  | CREATE TABLE 'temp' (
  'Column 1' int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |`

Comment: `0` for that setting?!?  Make it `100M` to get off the ground.

Comment: I found the installation already done and never checked it. Thank you for the hint. Does it mean this can be the issue and not the number of threads? Pls answer the question, not as a comment, so I can upvote and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should not be set to `0`.  It should be at least `100M`, up to about `1000M` for a 4GB machine that is running only MySQL.

This may be indirectly causing your problem.